# how to convert unsigned char array to QByteArray in Qt?

Tags: qt

unsigned char x[] = {0x7E,0x00,0x00,0x0F };

I want to push it to QByteArray but the QByteArray when finds '\0' stops copying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Which Qt version are you using? 4.7 has `QByteArray(const char*, size)` which should work and `QByteArray::fromRawData(const char*, int size)` which also should work.

Comment: From the docs, that form of the constructor has existed since 4.0. Also note that fromRawData() will not create a copy of the data until an attempt to modify the QByteArray occurs. Its usage requires certain guarantees from the caller that need to be carefully considered.

Answer (score 0):

QByteArray test("\xa4\x00\x00", 3);