# How to convert BYTE* to QByteArray in QT?

Tags: qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert unsigned char array to QByteArray in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911832/how-to-convert-unsigned-char-array-to-qbytearray-in-qt)

How to convert BYTE* to QByteArray in QT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QByteArray::QByteArray ( const char * data, int size )` to make a deep copy or

Use `QByteArray QByteArray::fromRawData ( const char * data, int size ) [static]`

to make a shallow copy.